# How to remove default layout's padding/margin

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following layout files:

activity_main.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0px"
    android:layout_marginRight="0px"
    android:layout_marginTop="0px"
    android:padding="0dp"
    >
    ...
</FrameLayout>
```

And some other fragments like

fragment_init.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragmentInit"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0px"
    android:layout_marginRight="0px"
    android:background="#549F07"
    >

    <TextView
        ... 
    >
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Everything looks fine in Lint, but when I execute my application on my Nexus 7 5.0.2, every container is displayed with a padding or margin of maybe 10 px.

This is illustrated by the arrows on the following image [image]

How to force the layouts to not add these padding/margin?

**Edit:** I should add how I insert my fragment.

Activiy

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, new Fragment_init(), "Fragment_init").commit();
    }
}
```

and I don't use any dimens anywhere...
Thks

Comment: It shouldn't show any padding or margin. What container are you actually replacing with your fragment's layout? And please refrain from using pixels - it's not good practice on Android.

Comment: Are you using anything from res/values/dimens.xml

Comment: BTW: you missed bottom margin. and do not use `px` units.

Comment: @Darwin, I just wanted to verify if I can override default margin/padding definitions but obviously, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: But there isn't any "default padding/margin" unless you set something yourself :-) EDIT: I see you added the `onCreate` method. Show us the XML for `R.id.frame_container` please...

Comment: @Arlind: Thks I effectively have activity_horizontal_margin and activity_vertical_margin set to 16dp in dimens.xml

Comment: @caBBAlainB Change that to 0dp and that should do the trick, but I really dont know where you are using activity_horizontal_margin and activity_vertical_margin ?

Comment: @Arlind now eclipse creates a layout with the following default attributes: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"     
     >

Comment: Yes exactly but where in your code are you using android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Go into this file `res/values/dimens.xml` and change the values to 0dp just like in the code below.

```
<dimen name="activity_horizontal_margin">0dp</dimen>
<dimen name="activity_vertical_margin">0dp</dimen>
```

Comment: It's what I did. thks

Comment: Where does the XML reference dimens.xml?

Comment: It references it from the main_activity.xml which is created by default when opening a new project. But it the question the dimens.xml is not referenced anywhere I just took a wild guess and apparently I got it right :).

Comment: That's exacly what I am looking for. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is already answered question but, i just come across such an issue, the answer helped but not completely, as there was a right padding. I found out that, it is because of the padding set in the Theme i used. It might be helpful for those still see the padding. All you need to do is remove it.