# How to fix imageview width - Not filling whole screen width

Tags: java, xml, android-layout

I'm creating an app that uses an ImageView in the main activity that covers the whole width of the screen, the height should fit the image's resolution.

Here's my xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:id="@+id/bgImage"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_home_blue"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's what my layout looks like:

[image]

Everything seems to work fine but I don't know where these paddings are coming from, I've tried to change the scaleType but nothing seems to work.

**Edit:**

If I put instead of src just a blue background, the paddings go away and it fills the whole width (than I need to set a specific height as well)

Comment: Check this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/29370345/5550161

Comment: It doesn't seem like a have that dimens folder, I just edited my question to give more info

Comment: Your image itself must have padding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your image is png and have that space around it, even when your scaleType is FitXY it doesn't mean that it will remove the space around the png file, check that out and let us know what happened, or at least upload your image file

Comment: Oh can't believe I missed that one... The image had a shadow that I didn't see, I just cropped and it worked, thanks guys